# CSS: How do I make text indent for a label with long text?

Tags: html, css, less

I have a list with 2 labels in each `<li>` , once the text in the second label gets longer the line break and it starts at the beginning of the next line, like this:

[image]

How do I indent the text to make it all start on same line?

```css
  .caspName {
  color: @darkTextColor;
  width: 105px;
  display: inline-block;
  &:after {
    content: ":";
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label class="caspName">Investment</label>
    <label class="caspData">Credit card processing</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4UKT2/

Comment: A `label` is used to associate specific text to a specific `input` (or `select` or `textarea`) element; it's *not* intended as a general purpose 'label' for anything else. Incidentally There's no 'a' in 'credit' (I know English may not be your first language, and I'm as prone to typos as anyone else, but while I was commenting anyway...)

Comment: @DavidThomas - I know credit card has no 'a' in it, just a simple typo. If I use `<p>` instead of `label` would it help?

Comment: It might, but it depends entirely on what you're doing; without context I can't really advise to the semantics of what you're doing, but ask yourself this: 'are the two sections distinct paragraphs?' If they *are* then use `<p>` tags, if *not* then don't,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like [this fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/4UKT2/2/) (I changed the `label` to `span`).

```
.caspName{
    width: 105px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -110px;
}
.caspName:after{
    content: ":";
}

li {
    padding-left: 110px;
}
```